# indexing and comparing string index or hash

Tags: ruby, string, comparison

I want to clean up my music-library by giving attention to songs that have the most doubles on my system. I could just list them all, sort the and do it manually but that would take too long. I want the list to sort on the most possible duplicates. So if a song would have 10 duplicates it would mean there are 10 songnames that resemble each other and thus i would focus my attention to that song first to just keep the best version.

I could compare two songnames using the using the levenshtein string-comparison technique and gem

```
require 'levenshtein'
Levenshtein.distance("string1", "string2") => 1
```

But let's say i have x number of songs, i would have to compare each song x times because i can't rely on normal filesorting, i would miss some duplicates then. eg

```
The Beatles - Hey Jude
Beatles, The - hey jude
Beatles_-_Hey_Judy_(remastered)
```

should give beatles - hey judy (x3)

Is there a way to produce an index based on the filename that then can be sorted and would give all the duplicates in descending order ? A kind of hash that can be compared ?

I know of other music comparing methods but they have their flaws, and this would be usable to compare other type of files also.

Comment: You might want to look at something like [pHash](https://github.com/toy/pHash) which compares the actual audio and gives a confidence level that they're matches.

Comment: seems an interesting gem, but after install when i require oit, i get C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/lib/ffi/library.rb:121:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library '.dll': The specified module could not be found.
 (LoadError)

Comment: Well you need to [download and install the phash library](http://phash.org/download/) that the gem uses.

Comment: thnx Andrew, i downloaded the windows library, under \release dll's are present, but where do i copy them to please ?

Comment: Sorry I've no idea, I don't use Windows. I suppose searching for where to put dll library files in general will probably be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code

`files` is an array of filenames, `max_distance` is a maximum distance to consider the names similar.

```
hash = {}
files.each do |file|
  similar = hash.keys.select { |f| Levenshtein.distance(f, file) < max_distance }
  if similar.any?
    hash[similar.first] += 1
  else
    hash.merge!({file => 0})
  end
end
```

After that you will get `hash`, which have filenames as keys and "duplicates" count as values, and you can sort it as you want.

Comment: i fill the files array with a few names and initialize max_distance to 0 but the result hash has all 0's in it eg {"Beatles - The Word .mp3"=>0, "The Beatles - The Word.mp3"=>0, "Beatles - Tell Me Why (remastered).mp3"=>0}, could you help me further please ?

Comment: distance = 0 means that strings are equal. As I wrote, you should choose a value at which filenames will be considered as similar. It should not be very big number, but not 0 to. Pick it up by experiment. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance for details of algorithm.

Comment: ok, thanks i got it, need to do some replacements first and take count of the length of the compared strings